# Imprimir icone colorido

Tags: html, impressão, restrição-único

Bom Dia,
Tenho um ícone na página HTML na cor vermelha:

```
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-2x text-danger"></i>
```

Quando mando imprimir, ocorre que fica em preto e branco.
Há como mudar isto com @media print ?

Comment: Você está usando algo que cria as classes `fa`-algo. De onde elas vem?

Comment: Não compreendi sua pergunta.. é HTML e o que está inserido é este código que citei a cima. Ele gera um Circulo Vermelho e na hora de imprimir fica preto e branco

Comment: Essas quatro classes `fa fa-circle fa-2x text-danger` estão vindo de um arquivo CSS, alguma biblioteca. Qual?

Comment: É de um template comprado. Usa os icones do font awsome, que estão internamente nos arquivos.

Comment: É quase certo que esse template deixe em preto e branco intencionalmente ao imprimir. Sendo assim ele precisa ser de alguma forma modificado e o primeiro passo necessário é encontrar e entender o trecho do css que faz ficar preto e branco ao imprimir. Sem esse fonte não tem como responder.

Answer (score 0):

Tente definir um estilo pra ele dentro do

```
@media print {
}
```

Comment: Como citei na pergunta, já imagino que seja no  @media print{}. Mas não teria um exemplo de como fazer-lo? Ou uma forma que não tenha de ser aplicada no media print?

Comment: Para que o pessoal fique sabendo a resposta vou postar aqui a solução:
@media print {
   .text-danger:before{
      color: #fff; /* Apenas um exemplo de cor. Pode-se colocar a mesma cor de Danger*/
   }
}

Desta forma está correto, pois no caso, de não conter o 'Before' não dará certo.